# How to Insert PDF,Image,MP3, MP4 Files in mysqli database into html php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload a blob data type into a mysql database using phpmyadmin. I am using WAMP as a localhost server, but the problem is this error...

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\
```

and this:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in C:\
```

The Exact Problem is that when I fill all of the required fields, then click submit, it does not inserting the data into the database and giving those errors.

The HTML code is named as `index5.html` and the phpcode is named as `upload.php`.  I created a database named `upload` and a table named `uploadfile` in phpmyadmin localhost...

Any kind of help is Deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance masters!

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll- 
transitional.dtd">
<html xmins="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;         
charset=utf-8" />
<title>RIP</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Upload Form </h1>
<form action="upload.php" method="post"     
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" 
placeholder="Username" /><br /><br />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"     
placeholder="email" /><br /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"     
id="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Php code**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","upload") or     
die("database not connected ");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if((empty($_POST['uname'])) || (empty ($_POST['email'])))
    {
        ?>
        <script> window.alert("Enter name & email please ..         
");</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        $uname=$_POST['uname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $image=addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $imagename=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image=file_get_contents($image);
        $image=base64_encode($image);

        $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into         


    uploadfile(username,email,image,imagename)values
    ('$uname','$email','$image','$imagename')")
    or die("Query Error ");
                ?>
                    <script> window.alert("Record saved ");            
     </script>
                <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I've checked your code in PHP 7.0.32 and it's working fine.

Comment: Hi, Im using PHP 5.6.38, is it because of that?

Comment: Hi, here is the update, I try to change the php version to 7.0.32 and test, but it is still the same of version 5.6.38 where I can only upload .txt files, but the rest cant be upload and encounters those errors

Comment: You can try to increase this timeout .add this in your php file  ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);

Comment: I put that after the query for server,name,pass,db and before if(isset($_POST['submit'],   now I can upload .txt .html .docx .png and sometimes .jpg ,but when uploading .pdf it always shows this ---> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\ <---

Comment: You need to add the following code at the top of your PHP page.

header("Content-type:application/pdf");

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the server side settings (the post max size, maximum execution time), depending on the size of the files you are uploading, and the database structure, the field  `image` must be a blob.

Comment: but how? is it on phpmyadmin localhost? teach me the step by step procedure pls, in the database, there are no problems. but what about that thing you said (server side settings?)

Comment: When i upload a .txt file it works fine, but in other file formats like, pdf, images, etc. it displays this kind of error. (Warning: mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp64\www\upload.php on line 20) and this (Warning: mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in C:\wamp64\www\upload.php on line 20) pls save me

Comment: pls help me study the code on how to create a proper syntax of accepting other types of file format when inserting in the database, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any solution on how can I insert the pdf type of file in the database? because I already using the longblob, but it still not works

Comment: Perhaps the .txt file is very small compared to the .pdf. What sizes do your files have?
For the server side settings, you have to find the php.ini file and check there the values for the specific variables. If the script runs out of memory or mysqli is not configured correctly then you might get that error. It might also be worth to check in PhpMyAdmin the configuration, look for wait_timeout and max_allowed_packet and increase the values for these. If you make any changes to mysqli and php.ini and you do not see any changes, try to restart the server before running the script again.

Comment: Hi, I am using phpmyadmin as a database server, would you pls mind to tell me where can I find the server side settings, and php.ini file? thanks

Comment: Hey, I find this in wamp64 by searching.......C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini..... and then i open it with notepad++, I scroll down and down, until I saw something...

Comment: ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M

Comment: Is that what should I modify?

Comment: I edited this things inside but nothing change....  
memory_limit = 96M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M